# Partial page rendering with ASP.NET WebPages (Razor)

Tags: asp.net, razor

I'm trying to update only content pages using WebPages and not MVC. I'm new to using Razor. Is there a new updated method partial page rendering with Razor or will the following work?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
<ContentTemplate> 
     @RenderBody() 
</ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Razor does not support web controls.

Comment: Thanks - any ideas with controls?

Comment: Oops, meant to say WITHOUT controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here for managing partials: http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/3-creating-a-consistent-look. If you want to update those parts asynchronously, you can use [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) command.